# Symfony 4.4 installation: How to resolve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've did a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation and also tryied to setup my Symfony 4.4 project which run on an older version of Ubuntu before without any problems.

Surprisingly when trying to access https://127.0.0.1:8000 the browser returns the TCP connection error

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**What I've checked:**

```
$ symfony check:requirements
```

Returns on the console: "[OK] Your system is ready to run Symfony projects"

```
$ symfony serve -d
```

Returns [OK] Web server listening, The Web server is using PHP CLI 8.1.2, https://127.0.0.1:8000

```
$ lsof -i :8000
```

Returns...

| COMMAND | PID | USER | FD | TYPE | DEVICE | SIZE/OFF | NODE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| symfony | 13656 | user | 7u | IPv6 | 103994 | 0t0 | TCP | *:8000 (LISTEN) |

--> Opening https://localhost:8000/ or https://127.0.0.1:8000 (and the same with http) in the browser returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

```
$ symfony server:log
```

Contains the following text:

[Mon Aug 15 10:28:25 2022] PHP 8.1.2 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:41109) started

{"level":"debug","source":"server","source":"PHP","time":"2022-08-15T10:28:25+02:00","message":"Reloading PHP versions"}

{"level":"debug","source":"server","source":"PHP","time":"2022-08-15T10:28:25+02:00","message":"Using PHP version 8.1.2 (from default version in $PATH)"}

{"level":"info","source":"server","source":"PHP","php":"8.1.2","path":"/usr/bin/php8.1","port":41109,"time":"2022-08-15T10:28:25+02:00","message":"listening"}

```
$ lsof -i :41109
```

returns

| COMMAND | PID | USER | FD | TYPE | DEVICE | SIZE/OFF | NODE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| php8.1 | 13671 | user | 4u | IPv4 | 103290 | 0t0 | TCP | localhost:41109 (LISTEN) |

--> Opening https://localhost:41109/ in the browser returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I've installed TLS succesfully by using symfony `server:ca:install`

Tested Chrome and Firefox but with same result.

Does anyone have an idea what else to check? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the first step would be to see if this was a Symfony issue or if you have some sort of tcp issue.  In an empty directory create a simple html file and try serving it with [php -S localhost:8000](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Hello Cerad, it worked. The simple html was served. What would you try next?

Comment: Try running `symfony server:start --no-tls` to perhaps see if the ssl stuff is going wrong.

Comment: Amazing Cerad, it really seems that httpS is the problem. Using "--no-tls" and "requires_channel: 'http'" resolves the problem. Do you have an idea how I could fix the httpS issue? Do I have to delete a browser entry setting made by Symfony binary? Re-installing it (first uninstall, then install) via Symfony binary didn't work.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to fix it.  I'm still on 20.04 myself and it all seems to work.  Consider posting a pared down version of your question on the Official [Symfony Discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions) board.  Might have a better chance of attracting someone who knows some of the internal details.  And just for kicks maybe create a new 5.x or 6.x project and see what happens.

Comment: Alright, thanks Cerad for your help!

Comment: As a reference to GitHub: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/47289